# calling Handler from a Thread leads to NullPointerException

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I need to call the `Handler` from a `Thread`, Here is my `Thread`:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}

        actHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }}.start();
```

I'm calling the `Handler` like this

```
actHandler=new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){

    }
};
```

Some times its working fine and some times it leads to a `NullPointerException` at the line
`actHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`

Here is all my code:

```
public class Casinos extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Handler actHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Please wait...");
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}

            actHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }}.start();

        setContentView(R.layout.casinos);

        actHandler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
            super.handleMessage(msg);
                pd.dismiss();
        }};

    }

}
```

What to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you initialize the Handler properly every time?

Comment: try this `if (actHandler != null) actHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);`

Comment: then how can i call the handle public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have instantiated `actHandler` after the `new Thread()` statement.

```
actHandler = new Handler();
```

Please show us some more code to verify but this is probably the case.

**SOLUTION**

You have initialised `actHandler` after the Thread declaration

```
public class Casinos extends Activity {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Handler actHandler;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Please wait...");
        //move this HERE!!
        actHandler=new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
            {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        };

        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(2000); 
                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
                actHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }.start();
        setContentView(R.layout.casinos);
    }
}
```

Comment: i added actHandler intialization now see it

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.arg1 = int value;
actHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

In your case if the looper processing the messsage queue is exiting then it will return failure.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you initialize your `actHandler`?

If it is in another thread, be sure that the initialization is called before. (the best thing to do may be an initialization as soon as you can)